# Is there a way to give a parameter back to the caller if the method fails, instead of panicking?

Tags: rust

This `impl` is for a struct which is intended to hold a list of cards, but has a maximum number of cards that can be added to it:

```rust
trait Property {}

pub struct PropertySet {
    max: usize,
    properties: Vec<Box<dyn Property>>,
}

impl PropertySet {
    // ...

    /// This function will panic if a card is added and the set is already full, so
    /// you should always check the set size first.
    fn add<T: Property>(&mut self, property: T) {
        if self.properties.len() + 1 < self.max {
            self.properties.push(Box::new(property))
        } else {
            panic!("The card could not be added to the set; it is full.")
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Panicking seems like an unnecessarily drastic response to the error of trying to add a card to a full set, so I would like to return an `Err` instead, but that presents a problem because this method moves `card`. `card` has to be passed by value because this is the only way I can add it to the `Vec`.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

Comment: That really basic stuff: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0295151cc61c97c436382c8b9f77bfa2

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom is to return the item as the `Err` variant of a `Result`, or embedded in it (like is used in `std::sync::Arc::try_unwrap`, so you could do something like:

```rust
impl PropertySet {
    /// This function will panic if a card is added and the set is already full, so
    /// you should always check the set size first.
    fn add<T: Property>(&mut self, property: T) -> Result<(), T> {
        if self.properties.len() + 1 < self.max {
            self.properties.push(Box::new(property));
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(property)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to adorn the error with more information, you could use a small `enum`, like:

```rust
enum HandError<T: Property> {
    HandFull(T),
    InsufficientBet,
    // ...
}
```

```
fn add<T: Property>(&mut self, property: T) -> Result<(), HandError<T>> {
    // ...
    Err(HandError::HandFull(property))
    // ...
}
```